# Arrow function parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

I'm doing some react tutorials and have this code

```
return (
        <div className="game">
            <div className="game-board">
                <Board
                    squares={current.squares}
                    onClick={(i)=>this.handleClick(i)}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="game-info">
                <div>{status}</div>
                <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

I'm quite new to js and do have some problems with arrow functions. When calling

```
onClick={(i)=>this.handleClick(i)}
```

how do I know what "i" will be a number or, to be more precise, and index? And how does js know what value to put in there so i actually get the index i need?

Comment: It won't be, it will be the event.

Comment: Are you adding content to the `Board`  element later?

Comment: `i` would only be the event. I would suggest changing it to `e` or `event` to avoid confusion.

Comment: In any case, misconception(s) about event handling aside, what specific problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I went over "my" code again and if I get this right it seems that at this point, I just pass the handler on to the Board-component as a prop. In there I pass this on even deeper to my Square-component as prop again where I make the actual call to the handler.

This happens in Board:

```
renderSquare(i) {
    return (
        <Square
            value={this.props.squares[i]}
            onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
        />
    );
}
```

And this happens in Square:

```
function Square(props) {
return (
    <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
        {props.value}
    </button>
);
```